# How can I change settings in Evolution under Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, evolution

After choosing **Edit** and **Preferences** I can see strange big icons with titles, but I cannot choose anything in that window. My Evolution version is 3.10.4 and OS is Ubuntu 14.04. Preferences window looks like that:
[Preferences window in Evolution under Ubuntu 14.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfbap.png)
I want to edit settings of my email account. Is there any other way to set this settings in Evolution?

Comment: What a blooper! The rest of Preferences window hide off screen at the right side. Anyway, this enormously big icons caused this confusion of mine.

Comment: Does that mean that the problem went away all by itself???

Comment: No. It wasn't went itself just without a prior knowledge of layout of Preferences window I didn't suppose that there is a part of window I don't see. Problem in my Ubuntu 14.04 still exists, but it is a problem with abnormal icon size now, and not in lack of possibility to change mail account settings. I check different themes and icons but i have still enormous icons in Preferences window. So I think that there is a problem in Evolution, not in my system. Maybe reporting a bug in Evolution will help?

Comment: I just restart Ubuntu and with icon set (before restart) to Default.kde4 icons in Preferences window are now in normal size. So, problem lies in icon theme "Flatwoken" used earlier.

Comment: One last (?) comment. At Github site of Flatwoken icons there is a open issue regarding this problem: [alecive/FlatWoken
](https://github.com/alecive/FlatWoken/issues/99) Unfortunately, until now it is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running the same version of Evolution and mine looks like this:

[image]

But I'm running on 14.04.3 Unity.

You can set the mail preferences directly in the config file:

`nano ~/.config/evolution/sources/nnnnnn@$USER.source`:

```
[Mail Submission]
TransportUid=1405846492.7444.1@fab-ux
SentFolder=folder://local/Sent

RepliesToOriginFolder=false

[Data Source]
DisplayName=Fabby Mail
Enabled=true
Parent=1392030387.8173.21@fab-ux

[Mail Identity]
Name=Fabby
Address=Fabby@Mail.COM
SignatureUid=1438771030.3264.0@fab-ux

Organization=
ReplyTo=

[Mail Composition]
DraftsFolder=folder://local/Drafts
SignImip=true

Bcc=
Cc=
TemplatesFolder=

[Pretty Good Privacy (OpenPGP)]
AlwaysSign=false
AlwaysTrust=false
EncryptToSelf=false

KeyId=
SigningAlgorithm=
SignByDefault=false

[Secure MIME (S/MIME)]
EncryptByDefault=false
EncryptToSelf=true
SignByDefault=false
EncryptionCertificate=
SigningAlgorithm=
SigningCertificate=

[Message Disposition Notifications]
ResponsePolicy=ask
```